# Call an anonymous function 100 times in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to solve the classic fizzbuzz problem using Elixir. I found a few different ways to solve this but the best way was this:

```
fizzbuzz = fn
  (0, 0, _) -> "FizzBuzz"
  (0, _, _) -> "Fizz"
  (_, 0, _) -> "Buzz"
  (_, _, a) -> a
end

fb = fn n -> fizzbuzz.(rem(n, 3), rem(n, 5), n) end

fb.(10)
```

My problem now is that I want to call the `fb` anonymous function 100 times. In ruby it would look like this:

```
 100.times do |i|
   fb.(i)
 end
```

Obviously, that wouldn't work because you can't call an anonymous function like that in Ruby. But I hope you get the picture. How can I achieve this in Elixir?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ you obviously **can** call a lambda in ruby as `fb.(i)`, it’s absolutely legit syntactic sugar for `fb.call(i)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
(1 .. 100) |> Enum.each(fb)
```

Comment: print a list of fizzbuzz results: `(1 .. 100) |> Enum.map(fb) |> Enum.map(&IO.inspect/1)`

Comment: When I do this IO.puts (1 .. 100) |> Enum.each(fb)
it only prints ok in the console.

Answer (score 5):

### Call Functions without Result

If you just want to execute a function `n` times without getting back any result (such as printing it to the console or casting it to a GenServer), [`Enum.each/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#each/2) is the way to go.

```elixir
my_fun = fn x -> x * x end
#=> #Function<6.52032458/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>

(1..100) |> Enum.each(my_fun)
#=> :ok
```

---

### Get Result Back

But if you need the result back, you should use [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2):

```elixir
(1..100) |> Enum.map(my_fun)
#=> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484, 529, 576, 625, 676, 729, 784, 841, 900, 961, 1024, 1089, 1156, 1225, 1296, 1369, ...]
```

---

You can also combine them together:

```elixir
(1..100) |> Enum.map(my_fun) |> Enum.each(&IO.puts/1)
#=> 1
#=> 4
#=> 9
#=> 16
#=> 25 ...
```